# Gabor feature extraction from an image

Tags: image, matlab, filter

I am trying to extract gabor feature from an image using the gabor and imgaborfilt functions from image processing toolbox in matlab using the following code. But it keep giving me the error

> Undefined function 'gabor' for input arguments of type `double`

This code is from http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-segmentation-using-gabor-filters.html just the image is changed.

```
A=imread('101.jpg');
A = imresize(A,0.25);
Agray = rgb2gray(A);
imageSize = size(A);
numRows = imageSize(1);
numCols = imageSize(2);
wavelengthMin = 4/sqrt(2);
wavelengthMax = hypot(numRows,numCols);
n = floor(log2(wavelengthMax/wavelengthMin));
wavelength = 2.^(0:(n-2)) * wavelengthMin;
deltaTheta = 45;
orientation = 0:deltaTheta:(180-deltaTheta);
g = gabor(wavelength,orientation);
gabormag = imgaborfilt(Agray,g);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a boring answer, but that's because this function was introduced in the R2015b release, so unless you update to the latest Matlab version you can't use it. Sorry!